# How to find the location of a python script if it's compiled to a .exe

Tags: python, path

I am trying some things with auto-py-to-exe and my problem is that the .exe file doesn't return the path of itself but a path to the temp folder.

I tried to use `print(os.path.abspath(__file__))` but that returns `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI154882\test.py` as path and not `C:\Users\...\Downloads\test.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) to get the path to the .exe file.

> A string giving the absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense. If Python is unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, sys.executable will be an empty string or None.